# Only after WebPack compile TypeScript in production mode I get exception TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "", when try save data to PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, webpack, typeorm

I use stack TypeScript, NodeJS server(Express), TypeORM(PostgreSQL). I use WebPack to compile TS and build application. When WebPack work in development mode no error occures. When I build app for production, WebPack switch to production mode and only at this mode I get exсeption TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "". This happen when I try save some entity. But not for all entities. This is due to relations between entities.

I have few entities: User, Category, BudgetItem:
User -> oneToMany -> Category
User -> oneToMany -> BudgetItem
Category -> ManyToOne -> User
Category -> oneToMany -> BudgetItem
BudgetItem -> ManyToOne -> User
BudgetItem -> ManyToOne -> Category

I can successfully save User. But when I try to save Category I get TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "". This error disappears if I delete all relationships (oneToMany, oneToMany) between entities, but if I add at least one, error will return again.

Cyclic dependency created because of TypeORM use decorators to create relationships between entities.

```
@OneToMany(() => Category, (category) => category.user)
categories: Category[]
```

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.categories, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
user: User
```

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

const { NODE_ENV } = process.env
const isDev = NODE_ENV === 'development'

module.exports = [
  {
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder

    entry: './src/index.ts',

    output: {
      filename: 'index.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      clean: true
    },

    mode: isDev ? 'development' : 'production',
    devtool: isDev && 'source-map',
    watch: isDev,

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    plugins: [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: './src/public',
            to: 'public'
          },
          {
            from: './src/.env',
            to: '[path][name]'
          }
        ]
      })
    ]
  }
]
```

TS config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["ES6"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./build",    
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

#### Webpack can't handle circular dependencies in the same way as NodeJS.

In NodeJS, top-level logics in a file run exactly at the time when it's imported, which makes circular dependencies possible to work. Though, for a webpack generated file, the real exporting is always done in the end of it. Webpack collects all the exports into an internal variable **webpack_exports**, then exports it at last, which makes circular dependencies always break.

Conclusion: **I can't use Webpack to compile typescript if I will use TypeORM.**

Solution: **I use Gulp instead Webpack to compile typescript.**

*I have found this explanation in the Webpack plugin [Transpile Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/licg9999/transpile-webpack-plugin#known-limit-01). They encountered this problem while developing the plugin.*